# html or xml parser as an external library (dll)

Tags: html, xml, dll, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I need to have an external HTML or XML parser to be able to add such functionalities in a software I'm developing using an uncommon programming language. It doesn't matter how advanced the parser is, also CSS is not really needed.

I know there are many libraries for C, Java or .NET framework, but these require you to include the source in your project, something I can't do since I'm not using a common programming language. I can only extend the program functionalities via external DLLs.

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you really need the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

I've used it embedded in several projects as a simple Assembly Reference.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I'm not sure what you are getting at by saying you want something external, but also can't use 3rd party libraries. If you really need to do so, you could wrap the HTMLAgilityPack in some kind of service layer that would allow you to execute against it.

Either way, without some sort of adapter, any library you choose will suffer from the same problems.

Comment: I can use external libraries (DLLs). What I cannot do is include the source code into the project, because it's not a common programming language so no libraries specifically written for it (in the same language) are available. Hence the need of a DLL or something equivalent.

Comment: @JoseFaeti - The HTMLAgilityPack is a DLL

Answer (score 0):

You may use HTQL at http://htql.net/